# Will this setup work?

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, varnish, amazon-vpc

I'd like to set up a Wordpress server on AWS with the following config

Server A - HAProxy for load balancing + SSL Termination
Server B,C,D - Varnish Cache Server
Server E - Nginx Web Server running Wordpress connected to RDS and Elasticache running Memcache

2 EC2 instances will be running from Account-A and other 3 instances will running on Account-B. All these instances will be interconnected through VPC Peering.

This is how I thought it would look like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GvaC.jpg

So my question is as per this document, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html#vpc-peering-limitations

it says, "VPC peering does not support transitive peering relationships" and I'm struck at that.

Will my setup still work or how should I go about going with the setup as described in the linked image?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the servers of both accounts are each within 1 VPC, the VPC peeering communication between the 2 VPCs will work as advertised. The transitive peering rule only applies if you would have a 3rd VPC you want to interact with.

Comment: True, and, even then, you can still deliver "transit"-like traffic from VPC A through VPC B to VPC C as long as you have an HAProxy server or Varnish, or similar, in B, because that's not transit traffic by this definition.

Comment: Marcel and Michael, Thank you so much for the clarification. It really means a lot. Since I'm going to use SSL, I think I can get the benefits of the SPDY protocol but currently HAProxy doesn't support SPDY but only the NPN/ALPN and I should forward those requests to a SPDY capable backend. Can you please give me a little hint on what should I do with my setup to get the benefits of SPDY? Thanks in advance.